# Setting `remove_unused_columns=False` causes error in HuggingFace Trainer class

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I am training a model using HuggingFace Trainer class. The following code does a decent job:

```
!pip install datasets
!pip install transformers

from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer, AutoTokenizer

dataset = load_dataset('glue', 'mnli')
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=3)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', use_fast=True)

def preprocess_function(examples):
  return tokenizer(examples["premise"], examples["hypothesis"], truncation=True, padding=True)
encoded_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)

args = TrainingArguments(
    "test-glue",
    learning_rate=3e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    remove_unused_columns=True
  )

trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    args,
    train_dataset=encoded_dataset["train"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer
)
trainer.train()
```

However, setting `remove_unused_columns=False` results in the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in convert_to_tensors(self, tensor_type, prepend_batch_axis)
    704                 if not is_tensor(value):
--> 705                     tensor = as_tensor(value)
    706 

ValueError: too many dimensions 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in convert_to_tensors(self, tensor_type, prepend_batch_axis)
    720                     )
    721                 raise ValueError(
--> 722                     "Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding "
    723                     "with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length."
    724                 )

ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length.
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the motivation for keeping it `False`?

Comment: @kkgarg I need `idx` in `compute_loss` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because the `value` in line `705` is a list of str, which points to `hypothesis`. And `hypothesis` is one of the `ignored_columns` in `trainer.py`.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in convert_to_tensors(self, tensor_type, prepend_batch_axis)
    704                 if not is_tensor(value):
--> 705                     tensor = as_tensor(value)
```

See the below snippet from `trainer.py` for the `remove_unused_columns` flag:

```
def _remove_unused_columns(self, dataset: "datasets.Dataset", description: Optional[str] = None):
    if not self.args.remove_unused_columns:
        return dataset
    if self._signature_columns is None:
        # Inspect model forward signature to keep only the arguments it accepts.
        signature = inspect.signature(self.model.forward)
        self._signature_columns = list(signature.parameters.keys())
        # Labels may be named label or label_ids, the default data collator handles that.
        self._signature_columns += ["label", "label_ids"]
    columns = [k for k in self._signature_columns if k in dataset.column_names]
    ignored_columns = list(set(dataset.column_names) - set(self._signature_columns))
```

There could be a potential pull request on HuggingFace to provide a fallback option in case the flag is `False`. But in general, it looks like that the flag implementation is not complete for e.g. it can't be used with Tensorflow.

On the contrary, it doesn't hurt to keep it `True`, unless there is some special need.

Comment: Indeed, I found out that I should remove string columns (`premise` and `hypothesis`) from dataset to resolve this problem: `train_dataset = encoded_dataset['train'].remove_columns(['premise', 'hypothesis'])`